# The advantages and disadvantages of using an assembler over hexidecimal and binary coding

Tags: programming-languages

What are the benefits and cons of using an assembler, rather than programming directly into hexadecimal or binary code?

Answer (score 5):

1. Readability.
2. Writability.
3. Usability.
4. Sanity.
5. Humanity.

I'll leave it as an exercise which of these are advantages and which ones are disadvantages.

Comment: I remember the time when I was a small kid when my father sat at thi kitchen desk and scribbled hexadecimal codes with a pencil next to a printout of a column of hexadecimal codes.

Answer (score 2):

It is not practical to program in binary or hexadecimal, as it would be nearly unreadable. Programming in assembly allows the programmer to write very precise instructions for the processor, while still allowing them to produce a readable and understandable program.